# What does it mean by "Manchu-language imperial archives make clear that is too neat"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does it mean by "Manchu-language imperial archives make clear that is too neat"?

Such ethnic divisions and hierarchies complicate boasts about 5,000 years of continuous Chinese civilisation. Official historians respond by claiming that the Qing so admired Han culture that they instantly assimilated into it, becoming the latest in an unbroken line of Chinese rulers. ****Manchu-language imperial archives make clear that is too neat****: the Qing retained a hybrid identity.

Answer (score 1):

A close study of the imperial archives (written in the Manchu language) shows that the official theory, that the Qing completely assimilated into Han culture, is too simple an explanation.

Comment: Thank you. So if I rephrased the sentence, it would be:       "Manchu-language imperial archives make clear that the Qing retained a hybrid identity, which is a far too neat explanation."

Comment: No. The claim that they assimilated completely is too neat an explanation. The archives show that it was more complicated - that the Qing retained a hybrid identity.

Comment: Manchu-language imperial archives make clear (that) that [refering the explanation before] is too neat: the Qing retained a hybrid identity.

Comment: So is there a "that" missed out? Manchu-language imperial archives make clear (that) that [refering to the explanation mentioned before] is too neat: the Qing retained a hybrid identity.

Comment: A first _that_ (which isn't essential) has been omitted to avoid repetition.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much.